# How can I get a list of all CSGO items including skin name, quality and rarity?

Tags: steam-web-api

I'm not looking for details of a specific player inventory, but a list of all items for CSGO.  What I want is details of the weapons in particular, but including skin name information and rarity.

To make it easier to explain this site has the information I need, except rarity.

http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/list.php

By using the following api url I can get weapon model names but not skin names (ie. "Zirka")
http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_730/GetSchema/v0002/?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I haven't found anything regarding skins in Steam Web Api.

Lists of all skins as well as rarity and corresponding weapons are in "**paint_kits**", "**paint_kits_rarity**" and "**item_sets**" sections of **/csgo/scripts/items/items_game.txt** file.

As for their correct names, those are in **/csgo/resource/csgo_*YOUR_LANGUAGE*.txt**. Looking like that

```
"PaintKit_so_red_Tag"                       "Candy Apple"
```

Won't be hard to make php or python script to get all of it and put it in a database for ease of use.

For skins images you could get weapon and skin name from the above, and do a foreach curl loop to get content from div with "market_listing_largeimage" class  using for example simple_html_dom.php, from url `http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/{ITEM_NAME}%20%7C%20{SKIN_NAME}%20%28{USAGE_THINGY Ex. Well-Worn}%29`

Just remember to replace all spaces going to the url with %20 but that depends on what you use to get the page. You could do a foreach on the usage thingy since some weapons don't have some variants on the market, curl could return wrong page. Nothing that a simple if+foreach couldn't fix.

Also do it only after skins update if overused you could get blocked from valve website for spamming. You could also use SteamWebApi and game news to check for new versions and update it automatically then. Just use your imagination and google.

Comment: For anyone else trying to do the same thing as OP and using Python, the following questions will be useful for parsing the files: [Parsing a CS:GO script file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946793/parsing-a-csgo-script-file-in-python) and [Parsing a CS:GO language file with encoding in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955019/parsing-a-csgo-language-file-with-encoding-in-python)