# Parsing a CS:GO script file in Python

Tags: python, parsing, format

I am working with some script files from CS:GO, I have to get some useful information from this file and import this data into my python application.

Here is an example of the txt data format:

https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/scripts/items/items_game.83a9ad4690388868ab33c627af730c43d4b0f0d9.txt

The values are in the random formats (Color\Pos\String), but i need just a string, which contains all of the values.
I need to get this information into the dictionary for example:

```
print(global_dict['items_game']['game_info']['first_valid_class'])
<<2
```

I'm working on parser now, but I was faced with a lot of problems. Is there any ready solutions for that file format?

Comment: It looks like it's nearly JSON, however without the `:` delimeter between the keys and values

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SteamDatabase/SteamTracking/master/ItemSchema/CounterStrikeGlobalOffensive.json
Yep.. and there is an example of json

There are also differences in [ and {

Comment: @CoryKramer: Don't forget the commas!. You could possibly read the file line-by-line and add the missing colons and commas and write that to a file. Coincidentally, I actually had the exact same question in my head today!

Comment: @CoryKramer: Hey, I [wrote a parser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35952455/1762224) because of what you said :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a pyparsing-based parser that will parse this format:

```
from pyparsing import Suppress, QuotedString, Forward, Group, Dict, ZeroOrMore

LBRACE,RBRACE = map(Suppress, "{}")
qs = QuotedString('"')

# forward-declare value, since this expression will be recursive
# (will contain expressions which use contain value's)
value = Forward()

key_value = Group(qs + value)
struct = LBRACE + Dict(ZeroOrMore(key_value)) + RBRACE

# define content of value using <<= operator
value <<= qs | struct

# define top-level parser
parser = Dict(key_value)
```

Load the config into a string, and call `parser.parseString()`:

```
sample = open('cs_go_sample.txt').read()
config = parser.parseString(sample)

print config.keys()
for k in config.items_game.keys():
    print '-', k

config.items_game.pprint()
```

Prints:

```
['items_game']
- sticker_kits
- client_loot_lists
- prefabs
- quest_definitions
- alternate_icons2
- music_definitions
- rarities
- colors
- campaign_definitions
- player_loadout_slots
- quest_schedule
- item_levels
- revolving_loot_lists
- game_info
- pro_players
- recipes
- items_game_live
- paint_kits_rarity
- paint_kits
- qualities
- items
- attributes
- item_sets
- quest_reward_loot_lists
- kill_eater_score_types

[['game_info',
  ['first_valid_class', '2'],
  ['last_valid_class', '3'],
  ['first_valid_item_slot', '0'],
  ['last_valid_item_slot', '54'],
  ['num_item_presets', '4']],
 ['rarities',
  ['default',
   ['value', '0'],
... etc. ...
```

**EDIT**

If you want the integer values to be converted to ints at parse time, you can define a parse action to do this. But you want to attach this (I think) only to the quoted strings that are values, not the ones that are keys.

```
# use this code to convert integer values to ints at parse time
key_qs = qs.copy()
value_qs = qs.copy()
def convert_integers(tokens):
    if tokens[0].isdigit():
        tokens[0] = int(tokens[0])
value_qs.setParseAction(convert_integers)

value = Forward()
key_value = Group(key_qs + value)
struct = LBRACE + Dict(ZeroOrMore(key_value)) + RBRACE
value <<= value_qs | struct
parser = Dict(key_value)
```

Now the output values look like:

```
[['game_info',
  ['first_valid_class', 2],
  ['last_valid_class', 3],
  ['first_valid_item_slot', 0],
  ['last_valid_item_slot', 54],
  ['num_item_presets', 4]],
 ['rarities',
  ['default',
   ['value', 0],
   ['loc_key', 'Rarity_Default'],
   ['loc_key_weapon', 'Rarity_Default_Weapon'],
```

Note that the integer values are not displayed as strings any more, but as actual Python ints.

Comment: Mr. Polywhirl, Paul McGuire - you are my heroes guys, i really impressed by your work and help! Thank you a lot!

Comment: Parsing is working fine, but I am once again at a deadlock when trying to make the next step, could you please look at it too at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955019/parsing-a-csgo-language-file-with-encoding-in-python?lq=1?

Answer (score 4):

As [CoryKramer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2296458/corykramer) pointed out, the file is ***almost*** JSON.

So, I have written a custom parser below, which parses the file by reading the source config line-by-line and writing the corrected JSON format to the output file.

I even tested the output using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and the file successfully validated.

> ***Note:** This code was written to parse any of the files located in:*
>
> `%STEAMINSTALL%/SteamApps/common/Counter-Strike Global Offensive/csgo/scripts`

---

To use the following script, execute:

> ```sh
>  $ ConfigParser.py -h
>
>  usage: ConfigParser.py [-h] [-s SRC] dest
>  
>  positional arguments:
>    dest               file where the parsed JSON will be written to
>  
>  optional arguments:
>    -h, --help         show this help message and exit
>    -s SRC, --src SRC  source config file
> ```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""ConfigParser.py: Parses a Valve configuration file.

The configuration file for the CS:GO game items is read line-by-line
and written to an output file. The missing colons and commas are added
to their appropriate places. The output file passed JSLint validation.
"""

from argparse import ArgumentParser
from shlex import split

__author__ = "Mr. Polywhirl"
__copyright__ = "Copyright 2016, Stack Overflow"
__credits__ = []
__license__ = "GPLv3"
__version__ = "1.1.0"
__maintainer__ = "Mr. Polywhirl"
__email__ = "https://stackoverflow.com/users/1762224"
__status__ = "Production"

# This is the default file that is parsed.
DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/\
Counter-Strike Global Offensive/csgo/scripts/items/items_game.txt'

def parseConfig(src_filename, dest_filename):
    out_file = open(dest_filename, 'w')
    indent_ch = '\t'
    curr_level = 1
    out_file.write('{\n')
    
    with open(src_filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if line.strip().startswith('//'):
                continue # Skip comments.

            level = line.find('"') + 1

            if level < 1:
                continue # Skip lines without tokens.

            values = ['"' + v + '"' for v in split(line)]
            indent = indent_ch * level

            if level != curr_level:
                delta = curr_level - level
                curr_level = level

                if delta > 0:
                    for i in range(delta, 0, -1):
                        out_file.write('\n' + (indent_ch * (level + i - 1)) + '}')
                        if i == 1:
                            out_file.write(',')
                    out_file.write('\n')

            elif level == curr_level and level > 1: 
                out_file.write(',\n')

            if len(values) == 1:
                out_file.write(indent + values[0] + ' : {\n')
            else:
                out_file.write(indent + ' : '.join(values))

        for i in range(curr_level, 0, -1):
            out_file.write('\n' + (indent_ch * (level + i - 1)) + '}')

    out_file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--src', default=DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE, help="config file")
    parser.add_argument('dest', help="file where the parsed JSON will be written to")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    parseConfig(args.src, args.dest)
```

---

### Additional Notes

It appears that there is a CS:GO configuration parser written in Java, which uses Antlr grammar to parse the files.

GitHub project link: https://github.com/valx76/CSGO-Config-Parser

Comment: Mr. Polywhirl, Paul McGuire - you are my heroes guys, i really impressed by your work and help! Thank you a lot!

Comment: Parsing is working fine, but I am once again at a deadlock when trying to make the next step, could you please look at it too at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955019/parsing-a-csgo-language-file-with-encoding-in-python?lq=1?

Comment: Here's a blog post about transforming Valve's VDF files into JSON: [***Valve Data Format VDF to JSON***](http://jwjdev.com/blog/dota-2-items_game-txt-json-for-developers). Johnson, J. 2013-06-03.